# C# Forms -> Click button in webBrowser

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to programmatically click a button in a iframe form in webexplorer. The button is a bit nasty though, as its coded not to always be active.  The HTML for the button is:

```
<input disabled="" class="submit ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled" id="btnEntryAddSav" role="button" aria-disabled="true" type="submit" jQuery1418076056597="6" value="Add ->"/>
```

I've tried using invoke but not having any luck

```
    HtmlElement ADD = frame.Document.GetElementById("btnEntryAddSav");
    ADD.InvokeMember("Click");
```

It just doesn't seem to actually click. I can see the button highlighted, but nadda happens.  Any thoughts?

Comment: my crystal ball says, you are doing something wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//in chrome
try
{
    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    HtmlElement submit = doc.GetElementById("btnEntryAddSav");
    submit.InvokeMember("click");
}
catch { }
//in IE try to find name tag and:
try
{
    HtmlElementCollection Bpic = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
    foreach (HtmlElement bp in Bpic) {
        string name = bp.Name;
        if (name == "input_name")
            bp.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
catch{}
```